# Ruby gem (method) which calls API and returns array of hashes successfully to rails command line returns nil when called from controller to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, parameters

UPDATE:
After the first response, I added some puts to the code and indeed, ALL of the requested data is being returned from the gem inside of the command line. This is not a ruby problem. This is a rails problem. Rails is taking a perfectly good hash and calling it nil. Ruthlessly, no matter what I do, rails calls it nil.

Basically, I have a method inside a gem which successfully runs when run from irb with a bin file, but when I run the same method from a rails controller (my gem mgmt skills are pretty good, it's not the Gemfile or anything that's the problem), the method returns nil. It's not a params[] issue either because the method call also returns nil when I manually fill in those params in the control (lowest code snippet)

So:

here is the rails controller (simple_search method returns nil)

```
def show
  obj = SimpleSearch.new
  @responses = obj.broad_search(params[:query], params[:type])
end
```

here is the broad_search method inside my custom gem (I've done all the correct "rake build", gem versioning, sudo gem install pkg/...., rails Gemfile and bundle install stuff trust me)

```
def broad_search(query, type)
  response = HTTParty.get("#{SEARCH_URL}/search?query=#{query}&type=#{type}")
  # the below parsed_response is going to be an array of hashes if successful
  p_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  p_response.map {|r| Results.new(r)}
end
```

class which API response is run through

```
class Results
  attr_accessor :identification, :picture, :address, :name, :type

  def initialize(input)
    @identification = input['id']
    @address = input['url']
    @picture = input['pic']
    @name = input['name']
    @type = input['type']
  end
end
```

bin file which is perfectly able to run the method and thus later parse (play with) the hash---in rails I'd be using these contents to save hashes to the database to begin to generate an archive of hash information

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path("../lib", File.dirname(__FILE__)))

require 'simple_search'
require 'highline/import'

class UI
  def initialize
    @search = Search.new
  end
  def broad_search_from_terminal
    type = ask("What type? Choose 'User', 'Startup', 'MarketTag' or 'LocationTag'")
    query = ask("OK. Assuming you chose one of the four types, what is your search keyword?")
    @search.broad_search(query, type)
  end
end
```

I would show the rails view file which fills out the params, but this also returns nil (outputted through inspect method, etc)

```
def show
  obj = SimpleSearch.new
  @responses = obj.broad_search("mark", "User")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the `broad_search` method in this way:

```
def broad_search(query, type)
  url = "#{SEARCH_URL}/search?query=#{query}&type=#{type}"
  response = HTTParty.get(url)

  puts url
  puts response.body      

  # the below parsed_response is going to be an array of hashes if successful
  p_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  p_response.map {|r| Results.new(r)}
end
```

and see what is different in each case.

Comment: ah hah! puts returned the appropriate url AND json hash! this is a lead, investigating now. Feel free to chime in if you're around and savvy to what's going on here

Comment: I've removed the last bit where I passed it through the lib class (Results.new), because JSON.parse leaves it in a good state for storing to a model or viewing. HOWEVER, again, while the rails console is calling this thing a ruby hash (JSON.parse results), the controller is in effect calling this thing nil

Comment: I just remembered that rails brings its own JSON parser through ActiveSupport. Is it possible that there is another JSON library involved from within your irb session?